# How to test the sample code (DownloadableFonts) in Android Studio?

Tags: sample, android-downloadable-fonts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkVRN.jpg)

Can I click the last option, Import an Android code sample to test the sample code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try it? What happened when you did?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can import code samples by clicking on that option.

A new window opens which allows you to select the sample, that you want to import.

You can click on the required one and test it.